# UpdatePanel refresh from client

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I'm trying to refresh update panel via Javascript:

```
  __doPostBack("<%=upMyPanel.ClientID %>", "");
```

But somehow its controls are all empty. On other hand they are all filled when I click any trigger control.
How can I fix this? 
thanx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK the UpdatePanel doesn't really postback, so your postback should be using a control that is registered for postbacks (i.e. the trigger control you speak of).

```
__doPostBack("<%=btnMyTrigger.ClientID %>", "");
```

Comment: Well i tried 

__doPostBack("<%=ddlScenario.ClientID%>", ""); 

where ddlScenario is an external trigger for this panel but still it does not work. IsPostback property is false. So it seems that this is GET request.

Comment: I think we may need to see a bit more of your HTML, without knowing exactly what you are trying to do it's a bit tricky :-)

Answer (score 1):

The UpdatePanel has no client-side API; third party update panels typically do but not the MS one...  You could try __doPostBack() as mentioned and target a control that posts to the server (like a button).

Try making the update panel mode to always to see if that works properly with __doPostBack.  Also, try the UniqueID instead of the ClientID.